# warden authenticate recall not getting called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have ajax login using devise, but I can't seem to get this working. The problem is that I have confirmable strategy enabled on devise, warden.authenticate! should fail on inactive users and render the `failure` action, instead it renders the default action. I notice that many tutorials have the same set ups. I am using rails 4.0.0 and devise 3.2.2.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   def create
     #problem: failure not getting called
     resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure") 
     sign_in(resource_name, resource)
     render json: {success: true}
   end 

  def failure
     render json: {success: false, errors: ["Login failed!"]}
  end
end
```

The devise.rb is set up as follow,

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :'*/*', :html, :json]
```

The routes.rb has the following,

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions"}
```

The signin form,

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, 
    url: session_path(resource_name), 
    format: :json,
    html:{id:"signin_form"},
    remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.label(:email, "Email") %> 
<%= f.text_field(:email, class: "field text") %> 
<%= f.label(:password, "Password") %> 
<%= f.text_field(:password, class: "field text", id: "user_signin_password") %>  

<%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "theme_color btn key" %>
<% end %>
```

Since the `failure` action is not getting called, the default `new` action is rendered with response header as follow,

```
Content-Type   text/html; charset=utf-8
Location       http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.js
```

I am also curious why it renders `.js` instead of `.json`.

Can someone point me out what I missed? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

After spending hours debugging the app, I found there's a bug inside devise's [activatable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb) file. As I follow along with the options and found that the devise's registered hook `after_set_user` does not throw with the `recall` option.

This seems only happen to inactive accounts(have confirmable strategy enabled, but account has not yet confirmed) trying to login with an existed email/username. However, if trying to login with a nonexisten email/username, the above does works as `authenticate!` throws :warden with the `recall` option.

I'm glad there's someone also found the same bug and provided the patch, but am curious why they don't merge with it. 
solution can be found
[here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/379d8c69a5c02dede6230719f3ebcc8bb95a655b)!

Comment: Holy shit!  I added your patch to my applications.rb file and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @SteveZelaznik can you share me the code, how you added the patch into application.rb file? facing similar problem